# Tire tearing, how bad is this for the long term?

Tags: tires

I bought new all season tires 2 years ago, they have just over 10k miles on them. Where I live I park on the curbs often, so when the front wheels are turning they're tearing against the curb and this is the result. How bad is this for the long term? There are only like two or three rips on both front tires, rear tires are like brand new. Also to mention they're suv tires 255/55/R18

[image]